# Comparing two string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a program that needs to compare any given string with a predefined string and determine if an insertion error, deletion error, transposition or substitution error was made.

For example, if the word **dog** was presented to the user and the user submits **dogs** or **doge**, it should notify the user that an insertion error has been made.

How do I go about this?

Comment: insert where - in database?

Comment: Thanks. But I am not using a database.

Comment: and will the predefined string keep on changing? or is it constant?

Comment: What does "insertion error, deletion error, transposition or substitution error" mean? Please provide examples.

Comment: This is most likely one of many duplicates of how to implement [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) questions. - pick yours at http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[c%23]%20levenshtein%20distance

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I don't think Levenshtein distance would work here because it would tell you how different the strings are but not *how* they are different (e.g. by insertion, substitution etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write a method for each of the individual error types to see if it's an error, like:

```
bool IsInsertionError(string expected, string actual) {
    // Maybe look at all of the chars in expected, to see if all of them
    // are there in actual, in the correct order, but there's an additional one
}

bool IsDeletionError(string expected, string actual) {
    // Do the reverse of IsInsertionError - see if all the letters
    // of actual are in expected, in the correct order,
    // but there's an additional one
}

bool IsTransposition(string expected, string actual) {
    // This one might be a little tricker - maybe loop through all the chars,
    // and if expected[i] != actual[i], check to see if 
    // expected[i+1] = actual[i] and actual[i-1]=expected[i]
    // or something like that
}
```

Once you build out all the individual rules, and you first check for regular equality, fire each of them off one at a time.

You've got to just break problems like this down into small components, then once you have a bunch of easy problems, solve them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head but I think this should get you started:

`Insertion` and `Deletion` should be pretty simple; just check the lengths of the strings.

```
if(originalString.Length > newString.Length) 
{
    //deletion
}
else if(originalString.Length < newString.Length)
{
    //insertion
}
```

To detect `transposition`, check if the lengths match and if so, you could create two `List<char>` from the two strings. Then check if they match using the expression below

```
bool isTransposed = originalList.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEquals(newList.OrderBy(y => y));
```

To detect `substitution`, you could use the [Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) and check if it's greater than 0.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to create a `function` which will take a `parameter` as the `input sting`. The `function` would look more or less like this. Use the `function` wherever you want then.

```
private void CheckString(string userString)
{
    string predefinedString = "dog";
    if (userString == predefinedString)
    {
        // write your logic here
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect word"); // notify the users about incorrect word over here
    }
}
```

Comment: That only tells whether the strings are equal. The OP wants to distinguish between an insertion error like "doge" for "dog" and other kinds of errors, like "dgo" which swaps two consecutive characters. I'm sure the OP already knows about the "==" operator.

Comment: Actually, that's the answer to the OP question; the issue is the OP question doesn't give us enough information to answer. @KeithThompson you are actually making an assumption of what the OP wants.

Comment: @AnthonyNichols - OP wants the algorithms to detect transposition, substitution, insertion, or deletion. I agree that not enough information is given in the question but it's clear that OP wants more than to just check if two strings matched (otherwise the insertion/deletion etc.. aspects wouldn't need to be mentioned)

Comment: @AnthonyNichols: The OP was quite specific about distinguishing among insertion, deletion, transposition, and substitution errors.

Comment: @KeithThompson OPs example states otherwise. i went with the example that he gave. nevermind though.

Comment: @PraveenNambiar: Did you read the same question I did? "it should notify the user that *an insertion error* has been made". If the predefined string is "dog", he wants distinct error messages for "doge" and "cat".